# Commonjs module in browser isn't updating local variables

Tags: javascript, browser, module

I'm using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` in the browser, and I want to cache these values to prevent a repaint every time I access them. I'm using browserify for bundling, so I've written this module:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var timeout = false; // holder for timeout id
var delay = 250; // delay after event is "complete" to run callback

// window.resize callback function
function setDimensions() {
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;
}

// window.resize event listener
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(setDimensions, delay);
});

module.exports = { w, h }
```

However, when imported the dimensions aren't updated when the viewport is resized. How do I solve this?

Comment: I'm thinking of exporting a setter, that can update the local `w` and `h`, and then initializing the eventListener in my main entry point. Or would there be better ways to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exporting variables with module.export you get a copy of the variables not a reference. When you update the local variables w and h the export isn't going to change.

Comment: So that would mean that there's no way to write a module that exports window width and height *and* can update these values on resize, right? Since only the values at the time of the first 'require' will be exported.

Comment: You can export a class with two methods which calculates the height and width when you call the method.